# flask-SQLAlchemy ArgumentError: Could not parse rfc1738 URL from string

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

buenas! Estoy trabajando en una aplicación web con Flask y flask-SQLAlchemy. va todo bien pero al momento de tratar de configurar la opción "SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI" de SQLAlchemy y añadirle un driver,  tengo el siguiente error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Could not parse rfc1738 URL from string 'mysql+mysql-connector-python://<user>:<pass>@<host>/<database>'
```

Aclaro que en donde están los "<>" puse en el código la información real.

Mi codigo:

```
class Config:
    SECRET_KEY = 'temporal secret key'
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql+mysql-connector-python://<user>:<pass>@<host>/<database>'
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
```

El error esta en que no me deja agregarle específicamente el driver "mysql-connector-python", usando "pymysql" anda todo bien. Supongo que el nombre del driver causa algún conflicto por los guiones medios, talvez.

Si hay alguna forma de poder usar ese driver, me ayudarian mucho!

Answer (score 0):

Según el [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14164183/python-3-and-mysql-through-sqlalchemy/15508403) en ingles el URIdebe de ir así `mysql+mysqlconnector://...`

Tambien installar `pip install mysql-connector` por si no lo tenías.